# issue displaying total row on devexpress pivot grid when paging

Tags: .net, asp.net, devexpress

I'm working with devexpress pivot grid, so I added the paging function and everything is working fine, the only thing I need to do is display the total row on each page, at this moment it is displayed just in the last one, I was looking on DevExpress documentation and it looks like pivot grid calculate the total and gran total automatically and I don't find any thing about my task, anybody knows how can I do this???

Regards

Leo

Comment: Did you post a new thread at the DevExpress help forums?  They're usually pretty good about checking those in case no one here has a solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible.  The grid shows group totals only at the line below the last row belonging to a group.

Comment: probably was not completly clear my explanantion hehe, the thing is that I have already a pivot grid wich does but is showing the Grand total and the pivot grid with the problem is calculating the total. if you want I can send you a screen shot from the both of them

Comment: Please post a screenshot so that the problem becomes visible.